# Estimate the Nevanlinna counting function for zeros of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $q,$ say $$P(z)= c_{q}z^{q} + c_{q-1}z^{q-1}+ \cdots + c_0,$$ where $c_q\neq 0.$

Then it is known that $$N\left(r, \frac{1}{P}\right)= q\log{r}$$

I wish to verify this.

For a meromorphic function $f$ on $|z|\leq r\leq\infty,$ the Nevanlinna counting function is  defined as follows:

For $0<t<r,$ we have
$$N\left(r,f\right)= \int_{0}^{r}\frac{n(t,f)-n(0,f)}{t} dt + n(0,f)\log{r},$$ where $n(t,f)$ counts the poles of $f$ in $|z|\leq t;$ $n(0,f)$ counts the poles of $f$ at the origin.

This means that the quantity $N(r,f)$ is a counting function of poles of $f$ inside $|z|\leq r$ and so the quantity $N(r,1/f)$ counts the zeros of $f$ inside $|z|\leq r$

Now given that $P$ is a polynomial of degree $q$ so it is going to have at most $q$ zeros inside $|z|\leq r.$ However I fail to understand how exactly we arive at the formula that $$N\left(r, \frac{1}{P}\right)= q\log{r}$$

Any help is largely appreciated.

Comment: It is strange that the formula doesn't depend on the polynomial at all, only on its degree. Take a polynomial which doesn't have any roots at all, then certainly $N(r, 1/P)=0$.

Comment: @Hume2: A polynomial of exact degree $q \ge 1$ has $q$ roots in $\Bbb C$  (counted with multiplicity), it cannot have “no roots at all”. But it is correct that $N(r, 1/P) = 0$ if the polynomial has no roots in $|z| < r$.

Comment: I read your question wrongly, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N\left(r, \frac{1}{P}\right)= q\log{r}$ can not hold for *all* values of $r$, e.g. because $N(r, f) = n(0, f) \log r$ for small $r$. Exact equality for all $r > 0$ holds only if $P$ is a monomial, i.e. $P(z) = c_q z^q$.

What you have is *asymptotic equality* for $r \to \infty$: All zeros of $P$ are in some disk of radius $R$. For $r > R$ is $n(t, 1/P) = q$ and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
N\left(r,\frac 1P\right)-N\left(R,\frac 1P\right)&=  \int_{R}^{r}\frac{q-n(0,1/P)}{t} dt+ n(0,1/P)\log{r} - n(0, 1/P) \log R \\
&=  q (\log r - \log R) \, .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
 N\left(r,\frac 1P\right) = q \log r + \text{const} \sim q \log r \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your explanation is helpful. However, I have a little doubt. Isn't $$N\left(r,\frac{1}{P}\right)- N\left(R, \frac{1}{P}\right)= q(\log r-\log R)$$ only when $n(0,1/P)=0?$

Comment: @Nik: $\int_{R}^{r}\frac{q-n(0,1/P)}{t} dt = (q-n(0,1/P) \cdot (\log r - \log R)$ and then then $n(0, 1/P)$ terms cancel. Or did I make an error in my calculation?

Comment: your calculation is correct.  Error was in my calculation which is rectified by your help. So thanks a lot!